# hadoop 2.7.1 pseudo distributed mode- Just seeing 1 reducer

Tags: hadoop

Recently installed hadoop 2.7.1 in pseudo distributed mode with Yarn on an 8-core, 28GB RAM VM with ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Our files are usually 20-40GBs so trying to find optimal configs for a single VM.
We've setup configs in mapred-site.xml (below) to allow running multiple mappers and reducers (using slowstart=1 to run them sequentially). 
I see multiple mappers but **only 1 reducer**.

Our prior hadoop (2.2.0) cluster was on 2-4 nodes so many configs below are from that setup.

mapred-site.xml:

```
  <property>
      <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
      <value>yarn</value>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>mapreduce.task.io.sort.factor</name>
      <value>48</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb</name>
      <value>512</value>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
      <value>-Xmx4096m</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>3072</value>
    <description>upper memory limit (MB) that Hadoop allows allocated to a mapper</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx2048m</value>
    <description>maximum JVM heap size for map tasks</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
    <value>5120</value>
    <description>upper memory limit (MB) that Hadoop allows allocated to a reducer</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx4096m</value>
    <description>maximum JVM heap size for reduce tasks</description>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
      <value>8</value>
      <description>maximum MAP tasks that can be run in parallel on this node </description>
  </property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name>
    <value>4</value>
    <description>maximum REDUCE tasks that can be run in parallel on this node </description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps</name>
    <value>1</value>
    <description>Fraction of the number of maps in the job which should be complete before reduces are scheduled for the job.</description>
</property>
```

core-site.xml:

```
 <property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/mnt/drive1/cluster/hadoop/tmp</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
 </property>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:/mnt/drive1/cluster/hadoop/hdfs/namenode</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:/mnt/drive1/cluster/hadoop/hdfs/datanode</value>
  </property>
```

yarn-site.xml:

```
  <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
      <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
      <value>24576</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
      <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled</name>
      <value>false</value>
  </property>
```

Comment: Where is your mapper/reducer code? What task did you tried to accomplish? Why do you think you should have multiple reducer?

Comment: The mapper/reducer code is too big to post and doesn't edit any configs. It runs fine here and we see multiple reducers in a multi-node cluster.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the number of reducers in your job? I believe the default is one reducer.

Comment: Also, I believe only mapred-site.xml is needed in your question. None of the others are the cause of your problem.

Comment: No, the command line does not specify any configs, just the input file, output dir and jar file. We've never needed to provide the config on command line before. That's why we use config files. Seems like some config isn't doing the expected on single node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml)

mapreduce.job.reduces defaults to 1.

Description: The default number of reduce tasks per job.

You can either override that value per job, or cluster-wide by setting that property in mapred-site.xml.

Comment: Let me try that. Mapper default is 2 but I'm seeing 12 being launched too.

Comment: Thanks! That was it, it's quirky (or likely lack of understanding on my side) that default is being treated as the maximum when maximum has been specified separately. Running a few more tests before marking answered.

Comment: I remember when learning that piece of MapReduce that one of those values is purely a suggestion :)

Comment: As pointed out, this config in mapred-site.xml did the trick. 
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.reduces</name>
    <value>4</value>
    <description>default number of reduce tasks per job</description>
  </property>